# When does webcrypto exportable=false protect a secret key from adaptive chosen plaintext attacks?

Tags: cryptography, webcrypto-api

When an attacker injects javascript on a page that has a CryptoKey Object with exportable=true, he can export the key and send the bytes to his own server.

With exportable=false, the attacker can't directly send the bytes, but it can use the CryptoKey object as an oracle for adapative known plaintext attacks.

Under what conditions can the attacker recover the underlying secret bytes and send them to his own server ? That is, in which case is it useful to use non-exportable keys ? Does it differ between the webcrypto algorithms (AES-CBC, RSA-OAEP, etc.) ?

Note: since the attacker can inject arbitrary javascript, it controls the whole api usage: the plaintext, and for modes using an IV (AES-CBC for example), it also controls the IV.

Comment: In the first paragraph are you saying that the attacker gets plaintexts? Does the attacker also has access the decryption?

Comment: @kelalaka: The attacker gets to create her own plaintexts and observe the resulting ciphertexts.

Comment: AES has resitance to known-plaintex attacks. It will help you, get pair to brute-force.

Comment: It depends on the underlying algorithm as to what can be done. For AES-CTR encrypted data, for example, the attacker could regenerate the AES-CTR output which would allow decryption of anything previously encrypted with that key.

Comment: @Jonenst I'm a bit confused, the title says `Adaptive Chosen Ciphertext Attacks` and in the body, `as an oracle for adaptive known plaintext attacks.`

Comment: @Jonenst I think we are talking here about the [key generation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API/Supported_algorithms) algorithms.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks, You're right. I fixed the title of the question. It's adaptive chosen plaintext attacks.

Comment: @jonenst What about he algorithms? are they key generation or there are crypto algorithms, too?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean. The questions is under what circumstances (for example, but not limited to, what choice of algorithms) is the secret behind the CryptoKey object safe.
For example, imagine that a webpage has a secret (raw bytes) in a variable A. Then it creates a CryptoKey with SubtleCrypto.importKey and stores it in a global variable B. then it erases the variable A. After all this, the user clicks on something that loads an attacker's malicious arbitrary javascript. Can the attacker recover the secret bytes by using the available CryptoKey object ?

Comment: Interesting question, and interesting comment thread.  As some of the other commenters mentioned, AES is designed to be resistant to known plaintext attacks, so I'm not sure it would be feasible to use an attack like the one described in the question to reveal the non-exportable secret key.  Nonetheless, a very strict content security policy would be advisable, to limit the opportunity that the attacker would have to inject the malicious javascript code needed to launch such an attack in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question:

With `extractable: false` you cannot simply export the key as it itself is encrypted.
But if you have access to the CryptoKey in a secure context you can use it as an oracle, sure.
But also not without caveats since the CryptoKey gets generated only for a specific Algorithm (eg. ECDSA-p-521) and whitelisted for what it can do (e.g. encrypt, decrypt..).
So if your key was generated for encrypting only, you can only run CPA, not CCA, and vice-versa.

with that in mind we can answer the bountied details:

if you have access to the secure context (via xss should work, mitm would be harder since it normally breaks https), and get ahold of the cryptoKey used in that context you can pass it to the `crypto.subtle.decrypt()` etc functions.
Keep in mind though, that you can only use the key for what it was designed to do, but yes the `decrypt()` function returns a plaintext promise which you could then forward to your attack server etc and use the infected context as an oracle.