# Can XSS replace an auth token/CryptoKey with a malicious one when stored in IndexedDB?

Tags: oauth-2.0, xss, indexeddb, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

Can an XSS attack replace a CryptoKey stored in IndexedDB with a malicious CryptoKey?

TL;DR

The WebCrytpo API allows creating a CryptoKey (which will be used to encrypt/decrypt/sign/verify/etc) with a configuration of {extractable:false}. This allows the key itself to be stored “outside” the browser (somewhere in the user’s device). Only the CryptoKey Object (not the key itself, but the object that references the key) is stored in the browser (indexeddb).

This mechanism seems very safe, but if XSS can just replace the CryptoKey object with a malicious cryptoKey object, is it really that safe?

Answer (score 0):

afaik the cryptokey contains the key (not just a reference to it) but in an encrypted manner, s.t. you cannot extract the encapsulated key.

(yes you can import it from a file, but you can delete the file afterwards the cryptokey object isnt a file-pointer)

and yes with access (through e.g. xss) to the secure context you could replace any used crypto-keys, but what attack would you run then?
what should the malicious crypto key do that you wouldnt be able to do with access to the secure context?

you might sign something in your (malicous key) name, but you could already do that.

a more interesting attack would to use the context and its crypto key as an oracle, as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53159882/15289577)

Answer (score 0):

If a CryptoKey is created with the configuration option **extractable=false**, means that the key material cannot be extracted from the CryptoKey object. This makes it difficult for an attacker to create a new CryptoKey object that references the same key material as the original key.

The attacker may be able to steal sensitive information or manipulate user data within the current session. Therefore, it is important to implement proper security measures such as input validation, output encoding, and session management to prevent XSS attacks.

No, an XSS attack cannot replace a CryptoKey stored in IndexedDB with a malicious CryptoKey.

The attacker inject code that can only interact with the current browser session and cannot directly access files or data stored outside of the browser environment.

You can check [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/252619/subtlecrypto-with-non-extractable-keys-stored-in-indexeddb-cross-origin-usage) thread for more info